# Unit test for function raising different exception

Tags: python-3.x, regex, unit-testing

provided the following code

```
from typing import Union, Tuple
import unittest


def split_value_and_unit(inp_value: Union[str, int, float]) -> Tuple[float, str]:
    unit = ''
    value: float
    if (isinstance(inp_value, int) or isinstance(inp_value, float)):
        value = float(inp_value)
    else:
        # get rid of = sign at the beginning of string
        str_value = inp_value
        if (inp_value.startswith('=')):
            str_value = inp_value[1:]
        if ('*' in inp_value):
            sep_index = str_value.index('*')
            try:
                value = float(str_value[:sep_index])
            except ValueError:
                raise Exception(f'Expected a string containing a float number and a unit. "{str(inp_value)}" does not fulfil this requirement')
            unit = str_value[sep_index + 1:]
        else:
            try:
                value = float(str_value)
            except ValueError:
                raise Exception(f'Expected a string containing a float number and a unit. "{str(inp_value)}" does not fulfil this requirement')
    return (value, unit)


class TestX(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_split_value_and_unit(self):
        # self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception, r'Expected a string containing a float number and a unit. "_0" does not fulfil this requirement', lambda: split_value_and_unit('_0'))
        self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception, 'Expected a string containing a float number and a unit. "_1+e16" does not fulfil this requirement', lambda: split_value_and_unit('_1+e16'))
```

I would have expected the unit test to pass. But running `coverage run -m unittest -v test.x` returns the following output:

```
test_split_value_and_unit (test.x.TestX) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_split_value_and_unit (test.x.TestX)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\klosemic\Documents\SVN_wc\trunk\Tools\ng_scripts\orchid_ng\test\x.py", line 24, in split_value_and_unit
    value = float(str_value)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '_1+e16'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception: Expected a string containing a float number and a unit. "_1+e16" does not fulfil this requirement

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\klosemic\Documents\SVN_wc\trunk\Tools\ng_scripts\orchid_ng\test\x.py", line 33, in test_split_value_and_unit
    self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception, 'Expected a string containing a float number and a unit. "_1+e16" does not fulfil this requirement', lambda: split_value_and_unit('_1+e16'))
AssertionError: "Expected a string containing a float number and a unit. "_1+e16" does not fulfil this requirement" does not match "Expected a string containing a float number and a unit. "_1+e16" does not fulfil this requirement"

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

If I swap the two lines that test for the exception (so if I pass "_0" instead of "_1e+16") the test passes.
So my question is, why is "_1e+16" a different case than "_0" for the test case? Especially as I explicitly handle the ValueError in the function (if that is good style or not is not the point here).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your pattern should be `r'Expected a string containing a float number and a unit\. "_1\+e16" does not fulfil this requirement'` `.` is a regex wildcard and and `+` is a regex quantifier and they will act as such unless you escape them. https://regex101.com/r/GPwpTV/1 vs. https://regex101.com/r/Z9O7tP/1

Comment: As an aside, I know you mentioned not caring about style but using `except ValueError as v:` and then `raise Exception('Some message') from v` gives a nicer message IMO.

Comment: @Axe319: Thanks a lot, I totally forgot about the regular expression characters! If you made your comment into an answer I'd happily accept it! Otherwise I'll post the final code myself

Comment: No problem. I posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.assertRaisesRegex` takes a regex expression as a second argument.
Since your regex expression contains a wildcard (`.`) and a quantifier (`+`) your string no longer matches.

For more detail see https://regex101.com/r/GPwpTV/1 versus https://regex101.com/r/Z9O7tP/1 .

The regex expression you are looking for needs to escape those characters is below:

```
r'Expected a string containing a float number and a unit\. "_1\+e16" does not fulfil this requirement'
```

Without it, the quantifier `+` will match `1` once and then have nothing to match the literal `+`.

Full code included below:

```
from typing import Union, Tuple
import unittest


def split_value_and_unit(inp_value: Union[str, int, float]) -> Tuple[float, str]:
    unit = ''
    value: float
    if (isinstance(inp_value, int) or isinstance(inp_value, float)):
        value = float(inp_value)
    else:
        # get rid of = sign at the beginning of string
        str_value = inp_value
        if (inp_value.startswith('=')):
            str_value = inp_value[1:]
        if ('*' in inp_value):
            sep_index = str_value.index('*')
            try:
                value = float(str_value[:sep_index])
            except ValueError:
                raise Exception(f'Expected a string containing a float number and a unit. "{str(inp_value)}" does not fulfil this requirement')
            unit = str_value[sep_index + 1:]
        else:
            try:
                value = float(str_value)
            except ValueError:
                raise Exception(f'Expected a string containing a float number and a unit. "{str(inp_value)}" does not fulfil this requirement')
    return (value, unit)


class TestX(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_split_value_and_unit(self):
        # self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception, r'Expected a string containing a float number and a unit. "_0" does not fulfil this requirement', lambda: split_value_and_unit('_0'))
        self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception, r'Expected a string containing a float number and a unit\. "_1\+e16" does not fulfil this requirement', lambda: split_value_and_unit('_1+e16'))
```

Alternatively you could `import re` and use `re.escape('Expected a string containing a float number and a unit. "_1+e16" does not fulfil this requirement')` as your pattern if you don't want to have to worry about always escaping special characters.